# unable to inject a service in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am using requireJS for my angularjs app.

**common.service.js**

```
define(function () {
    var coreModule = angular.module('coreModule');
    coreModule.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
        $provide.factory("CommonService", CommonService);
    }]);
    CommonService.$inject = ["$http", "$q", "$window"];
    function CommonService($http, $q, $window) {
        var service = {};
        service.sharedValue;
        return service;
    }
});
```

**page1.controller.js**

```
define(function () {
    var coreModule = angular.module('coreModule');
    coreModule.controller('Page1Controller', ['$scope', "CommonService", function ($scope, CommonService) {
        // Q2: common service
        $scope.commonService = CommonService;    
    }]);
});
```

Now When I am running my app, it throws me below error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CommonServiceProvider <- CommonService <- Page1Controller

any inputs?

Comment: Works fine in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24okrcLm/).

Answer (score 0):

Your core module should have  empty dependencies injected

```
var coreModule = angular.module('coreModule',[]);
```

Also in page1. controller you dont have to declare the module again, you can just use

```
 angular.module('coreModule')
 .controller('Page1Controller', ['$scope', "CommonService", function ($scope, CommonService) {
```

Comment: then how can I inject my ui-router & angular-animate?

Comment: you need to inject there itself, probably you have not shared that code here

Comment: What is required for module and what is injected into controller are two different things.

Comment: @Evilzebra yes, but he did not mentioned about the parent module, that is his issue i think

Comment: Right, sorry for my poor wording - I was arguing for your point. :)

Comment: @Evilzebra ha ha its ok

Comment: @BhushanGadekar did it help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Define config
2. Define the service
3. Define the controller, inject the service, use the dependency in function declaration etc.  As you would know, both are needed, after all you need the those handles, else what's the point in injecting.
4. Define a module, define module dependencies.  NOTE that the service has to be defined before controller.  If you reverse the order, you will get an error, probably that's what is happening here.  Without full code, I can't tell.
5. bootstrap angular.
6. Finally working plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/CE9enkgW3KASx8pf5vdb?p=preview

   ```
       define('config',[],function(){

           function config($routeProvider) {

           $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html', controller: 'HomeController'})
               .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});

           }

           config.$inject=['$routeProvider'];

           return config;
       });


       define('dataSvc',[], function(app){

           function factoryFunc ($q, $timeout){

           var svc = {getData: getData};
           return svc;

           function getData() {
           console.log('executing function');
             var d = $q.defer();

             $timeout(function(){
               console.log("firing timeout");
               d.resolve({name:"test", data:[1, 2, 3, 4]});  
             }, 750);

             return d.promise;
           }

             }  

           factoryFunc.$inject=['$q', '$timeout'];

           return factoryFunc;

       });



       define('HomeController',[], function() {


           function HomeController($scope, dataSvc) {
           $scope.name = "Mahesh";

           dataSvc.getData().then(function(result){
             $scope.data=result;
             console.log($scope.data);
           });

           }

           HomeController.$inject=['$scope','dataSvc'];

           return HomeController;
       });



       define('coreModule', ['config', 'dataSvc', 'HomeController']
             , function(config, dataSvc, HomeController){
             var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);
             app.config(config);
             app.factory('dataSvc',dataSvc);
             app.controller('HomeController', HomeController);
       });

       require(['coreModule'],
           function() {
           angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
           }
       );
   ```

Refer also,

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/

http://beletsky.net/2013/11/using-angular-dot-js-with-require-dot-js.html